# What is the best practice to transfer cross-protocol & cross-domain contents?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I know so many times asking this question and there had few solutions. But I still looking for real advanced answer.

I was tired with AJAX. Did everything in Google. But not solved. I don't like to use jQuery for this project need to do with 'XMLHttpRequest'.

Simply, I'm on https. But my clients on both http and https protocols. So I need to build a JavaScript API. It need to be like AdSense ad showing. Get few data from client's website and show my PHP process response. I was tired with HTTP headers and functions. Same result browser getting same origin policy errors. Is there any way to do this without using AJAX?

Comment: Why CORS isn't an option?

Comment: It's failed to transfer between https and http!

Comment: I don't think firefox (at least) will like **ANY** http traffic from a https page

Comment: Only option is server side `proxy` (for want of a better term) - what I do when I absolutely have to is set up a location on the server, lets call it `proxy.php` - which accepts as it's parameters a URL and whatever else is needed, it fetches the URL and spits it back to the client

Comment: @Jaromanda X, can you explain that? (Server side proxy method)

Comment: @Jaromanda X, do you have any additional links to learn more about that?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used PHP in over 5 years - google php proxy - first link looks promising